# Translate Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, translation, custom-post-type

I have made a Custom Post Type in Wordpress.
I want to show a label on the articles with the post type name.

I do this with:

```
<?php echo get_post_type(); ?>
```

It outputs the English name.

Now I want to translate it with Poedit, but this doesn't work.
My Custom Post Type looks like this:

```
    <?php


function register_cpt_news() {

    $singular = 'News';
    $plural = 'News';


    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( $plural, 'ndi' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( $singular, 'ndi' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'News', 'ndi' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( $singular, 'ndi' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Add New' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New '.$singular ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New '.$singular ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit '.$singular ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View '.$singular ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All '.$plural ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search '.$plural ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent '.$plural.':' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No '.$plural.' found.' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No '.$plural.' found in Trash.' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( $plural, 'ndi' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 4,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true   ,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-format-aside',
    );

    register_post_type( 'news', $args );

}


add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_news' );

?>
```

Wat am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method

```
$obj = get_post_type_object('postName') ;
```

then when you want to echo the custom post name by English use label name

```
$title_lan = $obj->labels->name ;
echo $title_lan ;
```

which you made it in English when you register your custom post

then when you want to echo the custom post name by other language use menu name

```
$title_lan = $obj->labels->menu_name ;

echo $title_lan ;
```

which you made it in other language when you register your custom post